# Keep Zurb Foundation dropdown open when clicking

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I am using a Foundation dropdown, and inside it I have multiple things I need to interact with, including colpick, adding and removing components, etc. Anytime I do any of these actions, the dropdown closes, as it should since it is a dropdown. Is there a good way to have the dropdown ignore my clicks and only close if I click the close button instead?

Comment: What type of dropdown are you using? It looks like the content dropdown here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html allows you to click around inside of it without closing.

Comment: Well I fixed two of the issues by doing stopPropogation on the events when I clicked things. I basically want a way to stopPropogation to all click events, so the dropdown doesn't close even when I click outside of it, then only make it close when I click a close button.

Answer (score 2):

Juts use aria-autoclose="false" in the `<ul>` tag (see section Autoclose in [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html#).

```
<a class="button" data-dropdown="autoCloseExample" aria-controls="autoCloseExample" aria-expanded="false">Link Dropdown &raquo;</a>
<ul id="autoCloseExample" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-autoclose="false" tabindex="-1">
    <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [foundation forum issue](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/692-control-dropdown-programatically) may help you